# Macro to delete headers if they appear more than once

Tags: vba, excel

I have recently developed a macro to consolidate around 70 sheets into the one sheet. The problem I now have is that all the headers from each of the sheets are now being repeated in the consolidated sheet along with sub headers I no longer need.

Is there a macro whereby I can easily delete the repeated headers?

This is my current code:

```
Sub Copy_Sheets_To_consolidated()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i As Long
Dim Sh1 As String
Sh1 = "consolidated"
Dim ans As String
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim Lastrowa As Long
Dim Lastrowd As Long
Sheets(Sh1).Activate
Lastrow = 6
Lastrowd = 6
    For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
        If Sheets(i).Name <> Sh1 Then
        ans = Sheets(i).Name
        Lastrowa = Sheets(i).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Sheets(i).Range("A6:N" & Lastrowa).Copy Sheets(Sh1).Range("A" & Lastrow)
        Lastrowd = Sheets(Sh1).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Sheets(Sh1).Range("D" & Lastrow & ":D" & Lastrowd).Value = ans
        Lastrow = Sheets(Sh1).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        End If
    Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Is there a way this code can be edited to only copy between two variables (e.g. the words Assignment and Client)?

Comment: To answer your question: No, there is not, you will have to write one. Because Stack Overflow is no free code writing service, please try it on your own first then come back with the code you have tried and tell which errors you get and where, or where you got stuck. Btw. It might be easier to copy only the data without the headers instead of deleting the headers later.

Comment: Please add your code so we can help you

Comment: I have added my code

Comment: Well if your headers are in row 6 then change `Range("A6:N" & Lastrowa)` into `Range("A7:N" & Lastrowa)` to copy data only and omit the headers.

Comment: The problem is the headers are repeated throughout the sheet. So they could appear in A6 but then again in A12, A20 etc.. (although the row number could change each time depending on the amount of data between the headers)

Comment: Are the headers the same throughout?  You could use `FIND` to search for the heading in a particular column and delete the whole row based on that, or after the import you can sort your data which will place all the headers next to each other (if your data is numeric this will place all the headers at the top/bottom).

Answer (score 1):

This method checks the header in a single column and then deletes the row based on that.  Use a column where the header will not be repeated within the body of data.

```
Sub RemoveHeaders()

    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet
    Dim rLastCell As Range
    Dim rFound As Range
    Dim rDelete As Range
    Dim sFirstAddress As String

    Set wrkSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Change sheet name to suit.
    With wrkSht
        Set rLastCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
        With .Range("A1", rLastCell) 'Change column reference to suit.
            Set rFound = .Find(What:="My Header", LookIn:=xlValues) 'Change header text to suit.
            If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
                sFirstAddress = rFound.Address
                Do
                    If rDelete Is Nothing Then
                        Set rDelete = rFound.EntireRow
                    Else
                        Set rDelete = Union(rDelete, rFound.EntireRow)
                    End If
                    Set rFound = .FindNext(rFound)
                Loop While rFound.Address <> sFirstAddress
            End If
        End With
        rDelete.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    End With

End Sub
```